# Want to run sencha-touch2 application in mobile remotely

Tags: sencha-touch-2, hosting, web-hosting

I have created a small application in sencha2 and am able to run the application on my desktop
i have put my application in XAMPP and am able to run it using localhost. Is it possible to test my application in mobile remotely ( android / iphone etc ). I want to host my application on free server for testing on mobile can anyone suggest me how can i do this ?

Comment: Do you have external IP to machine? If so you can directly access using IP

Comment: No Satish i dont have external ip.

Comment: Try using free hosting sites. http://www.000webhost.com/ this is one of them.

Comment: Thanks Satish, i tried the website given by you. But now i am using iphone simulator for testing purpose it works for me.

Comment: If you just need to test this on a device next to your machine and not out and about you can access your index.html file through a wireless router connected to the machine you are testing on.